# Android Studio Cannot add "Multi-OS Engine Remote build" configuration

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using Multi-OS Engine with Android Studio on PC so I need to use remote build for building an iOS application.

I have followed this tutorial https://multi-os-engine.github.io/doc/multi-os-engine/3_getting_started/3_remote_build/remote_build.html

But at the step **"Click “+” and choose “Multi-OS Engine Remote build”"**

There is no **"Multi-OS Engine Remote build"** avaliable to add in configuration

[image: Mine]

Requirements for Windows* hosts:

- Microsoft* Windows* 7 x64 edition or later (I have Windows 10 x64)
- Google* Android Studio* 1.5 or later (I have version 2.3.1)
- Java* Development Kit (JDK) version 8 (I have installed jdk1.8.0_131)
- Android* Platform SDK (It's installed in Android Studio version 25.0.5)
- Apple* iTunes* (I have installed iTunes)

I have met all requirements but there is no configuration to choose. How do I fix that?